# Bind ViewModel to CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

My Main window has a sidebar menu. When an item on the menu is clicked, I will render that item's page (UserControl) on a ContentControl. Here is what it looks like.

My MainViewModel

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SystemMenu = new List<SystemMenuViewModel>();
    SystemMenu.Add(new SystemMenuViewModel("Dashboard", new Dashboard()));
    SystemMenu.Add(new SystemMenuViewModel("Appointments", new Dashboard()));
    SystemMenu.Add(new SystemMenuViewModel("Reports", new Reports()));
    SystemMenu.Add(new SystemMenuViewModel("Configuration", new Configuration()));
}

private string _windowTitle = GlobalVariables.WindowTitleDefault;
private string _currentPage = "Dashboard";

public string WindowTitle
{
    get { return _windowTitle; }
    set
    {
    _windowTitle = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WindowTitle);
    }
}

public string CurrentPage
{
    get { return _currentPage; }
    set
    {
    _currentPage = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentPage);
    }
}

public List<SystemMenuViewModel> SystemMenu { get; set; }
```

My SystemMenuViewModel

```
private string _name;
private object _content;

public SystemMenuViewModel(string name, object content)
{
    _name = name;
    Content = content;
}

public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _name, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
}

public object Content
{
    get { return _content; }
    set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _content, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
{
    return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
}
```

My MainView on the rendering part

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=lstSystemMenu, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
```

My main problem is that I am just rendering the Content on my MainView without actually invoking or binding its ViewModel.

I am sure that there is something wrong on my implementation of the MVVM framework. Kindly enlighten me on what part did I go wrong and what's the best way to implement this one.

Comment: What types are `Dashboard`, `Reports`, `Configuration`... ? Are they other viewmodels, or are they UI elements? If you want to follow the MVVM pattern, then the viewmodel shouldn't have any UI element. In fact, I believe the system menu should be part of the view layer, or at the very least a service

Comment: Those are Views (UserControl). Can you help me how to display those views when a menu item is clicked without doing it the way i did currently? Oh and what's a service?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem and a more precise description of the problem, a proper answer to this question can't be written. Please don't post questions to Stack Overflow until you have read the introductory information, including the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the other articles about [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
Can't find the source zip, but the article has plenty of code samples.

What you need is to bind your ContentControl's **Content** property to a ViewModel/Model object, and **use DataTemplates to create the correct page depending on the datacontext**. The datatemplates just need to be stored in a ResourceDictionary, either the ContentControl's or some upper level control (or even the app). The DataTemplates must have a DataType set for this to work.

Also, as suggested in the comments on your question, the viewmodels shouldn't have a "content" property of type object. It looks like your "content" property is a view object or something. Can't know without you showing us more code.
**The ViewModel should not reference any View object**. But the View can reference ViewModel classes in the code-behind or in the XAML.

There are two ways to bind to the "current selection".
Either use the "current selected" info from the view list (**SelectedItem** for example), or add a property in the MainViewModel (ex: **SelectedViewModel**, and then bind the ContentControl to this property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I finally got it.
My understanding of MVVM is clearly very shallow. I am sorry if some people here are having a hard time understanding my question specially @Peter Duniho

I guess I'll continue lurking instead of directly asking my own questions.

Comment: No problem, MVVM can be hard to get right at first. Now that your view/viewmodel problem is sorted, you will enter the dilemna of where do some classes belong. Model or Viewmodel? Do I wrap every model with a similar viewmodel class that implements propertychange? There are plenty of answers here on SO. Always remember that MVVM does not only apply to WPF. A good MVVM project could have different view implementations (wpf, winform, uwp, console, etc) without changing a single line of shared viewmodel code.